# How to check each item listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

This is a simple code but is really wash my brain .. move to any position code cannot helped. below is to checking each item from listview before add new item from combobox. unfortunately checking only work for last item. Help me. Thanks in advance

```
Dim checkType As String
        Dim checkSubType As String
        Dim TempNode As ListViewItem
        For Each TempNode In ListView1.Items
            checkSubType = TempNode.SubItems.Item(0).Text
            checkType = TempNode.SubItems.Item(1).Text
        Next

        If ComboBox1.Text = checkSubType AndAlso ComboBox2.Text = checkType Then
            With ListView1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text, 0)
                .SubItems.Add(ComboBox2.Text)
                .SubItems.Add("DUPLICATE")
            End With
        Else
            With ListView1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text, 0)
                .SubItems.Add(ComboBox2.Text)
                .SubItems.Add("ADD NEW")
            End With
        End If
```

SOLUTION :

```
 Dim total As Integer
        If ListView1.View = View.Details AndAlso ListView1.Items.Count > 0 Then
            'Dim lvi As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(ComboBox1.Text, True, 0)
            Dim lva As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(ComboBox2.Text, True, 0)

            If lva IsNot Nothing Then
                '......
            Else
                '......
            End If
        Else
            '......
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is  in your For Each loop. Every time you loop, you are blowing away the old values in checkSubType and checkType and saving new values over them. This is why only the last items are being checked.

```
Dim checkType as List(Of String) = new List(Of String)
Dim checkSubType as List(Of String) = new List(Of String)


For Each TempNode In ListView1.Items
        checkSubType.Add(TempNode.SubItems.Item(0).Text)
        checkType.Add(TempNode.SubItems.Item(1).Text)
Next
```

At this point you now have two lists full of the items, they can then be checked.

Or you could try something like this

```
Dim checkType As String
    Dim checkSubType As String
    Dim TempNode As ListViewItem

    For value As Integer 0 To ListView1.Items.Count
        checkSubType = TempNode.SubItems.Item(0).Text
        checkType = TempNode.SubItems.Item(1).Text


    If ComboBox1.Text = checkSubType AndAlso ComboBox2.Text = checkType Then
        With ListView1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text, 0)
            .SubItems.Add(ComboBox2.Text)
            .SubItems.Add("DUPLICATE")
        End With
    Else
        With ListView1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text, 0)
            .SubItems.Add(ComboBox2.Text)
            .SubItems.Add("ADD NEW")
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, but where I put "if permission" if I use first advice code because the second advice error at TempNode. :)

Comment: Mathemats: And I have tried the second code but when detected duplicate, listview multiple entry caused by listview count